# how to write this php array output an input

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array output from some function

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => [layout] => b [limit] => 10 [top_layout] => 0 [top_limit] => 2 [time] => 0 [order] => date [manual] => [action] => pagination [pagination] => numeric [action_link_text] => View all [action_link_url] => http:// ) )
```

how do i write it as an input to some variable 
is it?

```
$var = array (array ('title' => 'layout' => 'b', 'limit' => 10, 'top_layout' = > '0', 'top_limit' => '2', 'time' => '0' , 'order' = > 'date' , 'manual' = > 'action => 'pagination' , 'pagination' , 'numeric' , 'action_link_text' = > 'View all', 'action_link_url' => 'http://'))
```

Comment: `$var = function();` where is the problem?

Comment: um, just ass ign it? What you show is print_r representation of the array, not the actual array.

Comment: i don't wan't to use the function, i wold like to write the print_r output as an input

Comment: @MightyPork Or it's a really funny string and a weird function :D

Comment: @tm81 When you get the data from the function, how do you want to NOT use the function ?! Logic is missing here!

Comment: I also like to print out my e-mails and then scan them and save them to disk, instead of doing it directly. It's MORE BADASS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
$var = print_r($input, true);
```